# docker v20.10.22 in windows : Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-desktop, orchestration

I installed Docker desktop latest version (Docker Engine - v20.10.22).

1. pointed it to search containers in Windows.
2. run the command docker --help (it is working okay)

Now when I am trying to run any command I am getting this error.

> docker Error response from daemon: open
> \.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file
> specified.

[image: Docker pull redis command]
[image: Configuration which is currently used]
[image: Quick menu of docker desktop]
[image: Docker Search redis]

did by any chance someone gets this error and got it resolved ?